# Installer does not detect windows 10

Tags: 16.04, windows

I followed some instructions which I found on youtube, all was going smoothly untill it said that there is no operating system installed which clearly is wrong since I have windows 10 installed. I do not want to unistall windows 10, but run Ubuntu as a dual-boot. I tried googling for answers but the problem is that I do not understand any of the instructions I find there. I do not know a thing about computers. I think I could get it to work if someone would tell me exactly what to do. That would mean the world to me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered manually shrinking your windows 10 partition from windows and then installing ubuntu into the free space. This is usually a trouble free method. [Instructions to shrink from windows](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-shrink-windows-10-to-make-space.html)

Answer (score 6):

The Windows file system looks dirty to Ubuntu, so the Ubuntu installer can't see that Windows is there. This is because Windows uses a hibernation file to save the system state.

You'll need to do this in Windows:

- open the Power control panel
- click on `change what the power buttons do`
- click on `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast start`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off` *(turns off hibernation)*
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve that chkdsk runs at next boot time
- reboot Windows

Then retry the Ubuntu installer and you'll probably have better luck.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, unfortunately it still does not recognise the windows 10

Comment: @MarttiKaasalainen then review the post by karel and see if something there works for you.

Comment: @MarttiKaasalainen did you go through ALL of my steps, including rebooting Windows?

Comment: I can't uncheck fast start unless I enable hibernation, so I did that before unchecking fast start, otherwise I did just as you said

Comment: @MarttiKaasalainen that's correct. If you re-enable hibernation, you could re-check the `fast start` setting, and then disable hibernation again. The rebooting of Windows is most important after doing the other steps.

Comment: That is how I did it

Comment: @MarttiKaasalainen then unfortunately my solution isn't going to help you. Check the post by karel for more things to check. Like the Windows partition being too full, etc.

Comment: @MarttiKaasalainen if you're going to `shrink` the Windows partition manually, make sure that you do this **from Windows**, using **Windows Disk Management** application. Don't use the Ubuntu installer or `gparted`.

Comment: That is how I did it. But I already went and uninstalle w10 and I'm running only ubuntu now